# iOS - Get unique values from multiple arrays using the same order

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have 2 arrays:

Array one: `(@"26", @"26", @"25", @"25", @"3", @"3", @"4", @"4")`

Array two: `(@"sticker", @"sticker", @"sticker", @"sticker", @"sticker", @"frame", @"frame", @"frame")`

**Edit**

These 2 arrays are connected like this:

```
26 - sticker
26 - sticker
25 - sticker
25 - sticker
3 - frame
3 - frame
4 - frame
4 - frame
```

I'm getting unique value in array one and putting it in another array like this:

```
NSArray *uniqueArrayOne = [[NSSet setWithArray:arrayOne] allObjects];
```

So uniqueArrayOne looks like this:

```
(26, 25, 3, 4)
```

I want `uniqueArrayTwo` to also be arrange like how `uniqueArrayOne` was arranged. I want `uniqueArrayTwo` to look like this:

```
(sticker, sticker, frame, frame)
```

What do I do?

**Edit**

Here is another example:

Array one: `(@"TONY", @"SANSA", @"BILL", @"BILL", @"STEVE", @"STEVE")`

Array two: `(@"STARK", @"STARK", @"GATES", @"GATES", @"JOBS", @"JOBS")`

The results should be like this:

uniqueArrayOne :`(TONY, SANSA, BILL, STEVE)`

uniqueArrayTwo :`(STARK, STARK, GATES, JOBS)`

`uniqueArrayTwo` is arrange depending on `uniqueArrayOne`.

Comment: You have to clarify that you want the second instance of each number form the first array.  It's not at all obvious from the question.

Comment: Actually, you aren't at all consistent.  Perhaps you left out a `frame`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn an NSArray of strings into an array of unique strings, in the same order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209823/how-to-turn-an-nsarray-of-strings-into-an-array-of-unique-strings-in-the-same-o)

Comment: @FahimParkar I already looked at that answer. It is similar but not a duplicate.

Comment: @imstillalive : for sure that answer will help you 99%...

Comment: I agree with @fahim-parkar, the answers on that question get you most of the way there.  (I wouldn't say quite 99%.)

Comment: Why don't you use a `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` instead of `arrayOne` and `arrayTwo` => `NSArray *array = @[@{@"Name:"@"Tony", @"FamilyName":@"Stark"},@{@"Name:"@"Sansa", @"FamilyName":@"Stark"}, @{@"Name:"@"Bill", @"FamilyName":@"Gates"} ]`? You are trying to synchronize the items on two separates array where putting it in only may be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it this way

```
- (void)uniqueArrayFinder
{
    NSArray *array1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       @"TONY", @"SANSA", @"BILL", @"BILL", @"STEVE", @"STEVE",nil];
    NSArray *array2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       @"STARK", @"STARK", @"GATES", @"GATES", @"JOBS", @"JOBS",nil];

    NSMutableArray *combinedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<[array1 count];i++)
    {
        NSString *arrayVal1 = [array1 objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *arrayVal2 = [array2 objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *combinedStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", arrayVal1, arrayVal2];
        [combinedArray addObject:combinedStr];
    }

    //this gives uniqe values
    NSSet *uniqueEvents = [NSSet setWithArray:combinedArray];
    [combinedArray removeAllObjects];
    [combinedArray addObjectsFromArray:[uniqueEvents allObjects]];

    NSLog(@"combinedArray: %@ ...", combinedArray);


}
```

Output:

```
combinedArray: (
    "STEVE JOBS",
    "TONY STARK",
    "SANSA STARK",
    "BILL GATES"
) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result with the following,

```
NSArray *arr1 = @[@"26", @"26", @"25", @"25", @"3", @"3", @"4", @"4"];
NSArray *arr2 = @[@"sticker", @"sticker", @"sticker", @"sticker", @"sticker", @"frame", @"frame", @"frame"];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arr2 
                                   forKeys:arr1];

NSArray *distinctArr1 = [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:arr1] array];

NSMutableArray *distinctArr2 = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *num1 in distinctArr1) {
    [distinctArr2 addObject:dict[num1]];
}
// Your distinctArr2 is sorted based on distinctArr1's indices
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
NSArray *arrayOne = @[@"TONY", @"SANSA", @"BILL", @"BILL", @"STEVE", @"STEVE"];
NSArray *arrayTwo = @[@"STARK", @"STARK", @"GATES", @"GATES", @"JOBS", @"JOBS"];

NSArray *uniqueArrayOne = [[NSSet setWithArray:arrayOne] allObjects];
NSMutableArray *uniqueArrayTwo = [NSMutableArray array];

[uniqueArrayOne enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj1, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSUInteger found = [arrayOne indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull obj2, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        return [(NSString *)obj2 isEqualToString:(NSString *)obj1];
    }];
    [uniqueArrayTwo addObject:[arrayTwo objectAtIndex:found]];
}];

NSLog(@"%@, %@", uniqueArrayOne, uniqueArrayTwo);
```