# distinctUnionOfObjects changes the order of an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting, nsmutablearray

Below is my original array :

```
{
    FilePath = "Selfcare.jpg";
    ModuleId = 18;
    ModuleName = "Infant N Toddler";
    SkillLevelID = 59;
    SkillLevelName = "Self Care";
},
{
    FilePath = "Preschool.jpg";
    ModuleId = 18;
    ModuleName = "Infant N Toddler";
    SkillLevelID = 60;
    SkillLevelName = "Preschool Readiness";
},
{
    FilePath = "Learning_Primary.jpg";
    ModuleId = 22;
    ModuleName = Cognitive;
    SkillLevelID = 71;
    SkillLevelName = "Learning Readiness - Primary Skills";
},
{
    FilePath = "PreAcad_Primary.jpg";
    ModuleId = 22;
    ModuleName = Cognitive;
    SkillLevelID = 72;
    SkillLevelName = "Pre-Academics: Primary Skills";
}
```

when I apply distinctUnionOfObjects

```
NSArray *curriculums = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.ModuleName"];
```

this changes the order giving me resulting array

```
<__NSArrayI>(
Cognitive,
Infant N Toddler
)
```

It should give

```
<__NSArrayI>(
    Infant N Toddler,
    Cognitive
    )
```

as per original array order.

How do I restrict this order change?

Comment: ***it'll give you an array of uniqued values in ModuleName, and you
can't guarantee the order to be preserved***

Comment: u sure the order cannot be change? :(

Comment: any other way to get the same output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn an NSArray of strings into an array of unique strings, in the same order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209823/how-to-turn-an-nsarray-of-strings-into-an-array-of-unique-strings-in-the-same-o)

Comment: but your SkillLevelID is different

Comment: please try this one     NSArray *orderedSet = [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:[people valueForKey:@"ModuleName"]] array];

Comment: great man @Birendra

Comment: you can add it in answers. This achieves the goal. yey!

Comment: @Vishnugondlekar looping is also the solution. But I will have hundreds of elements into the array. so looping every time is not feasible. Anyway thank u so much for you time too. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please try this one

```
NSArray *orderedSet = [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:[people valueForKey:@"ModuleName"]] array];
```